# Mysterious translucent rectangle box appears bottom left of win10 after latest update

Tags: windows, windows-10, troubleshooting

I had to move the task bar to the side so it wouldnt cover the box in question. you can see the box here http://prntscr.com/o1l01u

That box is visible mainly when in full screen, such as background only or playing a game etc. its always there. I dont think it was there prior to yesterday's windows 10 update to latest version (version 1903).

Anyone know what it is and how to get rid of it?

PS: I just clicked on my own link, only to realize that screen capture doesnt reproduce that box. Thought I was going crazy for a second. Its there bottom left side behind the Search. But its only visible in full screen and without the bar covering it.

So I took the shot with my trusty iPhone instead and here's how it looks http://prntscr.com/o1l2gn

Comment: That looks the size and position of the Cortana search box. As a test, try hiding it and see if it goes away (right click on the taskbar) https://i.imgur.com/s6PtaZw.png

Comment: "yesterday's Windows 10 update to the latest version." - Please edit your question to indicate which cumulative update was installed.  This will indicate which version of Windows 10 you are using.

Comment: @Ramhound updated my post. its version 1903.

Comment: @wysiwyg I switched it off, the box is still there.

Comment: Does it appear if you boot in Safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc Actually I am not able to access safe mode. Hitting F8, lists my 4 drives and the option to enter setup. How do I go about it?

Comment: Very strange and disturbing. There are other methods, see [Start your PC in safe mode in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for that. my Windows Key sometimes works sometimes doesnt (also weird), so i got an obstacle there too. Was finally able to boot safe mode, but bar and background and everything else was black, so it was really hard to tell, but seems like that box wasnt there (95% certainty). On a side note,this box only appears on my primary monitor, while safe mode only opened on my secondary. I dont think thats relevant, but thought i'd mention it.